# How to encode a string in base64 to be used in a URL?

Tags: php, base64, encode

I need to attach a confirmation code that can hold several parts and almost `random` characters, to an email.
The idea is to print the URL with that code in the message body (in HTML).

Is the `base64_encode()` function enough to make it safe to be parsed by the browser ?

Comment: Are you really putting binary characters into the confirmation code? If it's just letters and numbers there's no need to encode it.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I didnt choose the format of that code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base64 encoding is to take binary data and make it suitable for being treated as text.

That isn't your problem (you said you had random *characters*) so you shouldn't use Base64.

You have text and want to insert it into a URL. You need to URL encode it. That is what the [`urlencode()` function](http://php.net/urlencode) is for.

You then want to insert that URL in an HTML document. That is what the [`htmlspecialchars()` function](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is for.

```
$data = function_to_get_random_data();
$url_safe_data = urlencode($data);
$url = "http://example.com/$url_safe_data";
$html_safe_url = htmlspecialchars($url);
$html = "<a href=\"$html_safe_url\">$html_safe_url</a>";
```